# How to enter solutions in LHS of an equation using loop to check RHS

Tags: equation-solving, import, data, procedural-programming

Suppose I get 1 million values of a, b after solving the equation 
ax+by^2 =0. Then how to again put the values of a and b in the LHS of the given equation using a loop in order to check if the RHS of the equation is zero or not?